# read data from excel and create a chart on the same excel Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am new in Python I am trying to read a excel file which can have multiple sheets. read all the sheets and create a chart for each sheet on the same sheet . I tried below code but this is creating chart on localhost.

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'sample.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
#print(df)

data = [go.Scatter(x=df['Data'], y=df['Current'])]
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

Below will be the format of data on each sheet of the excel

```
 Data       Current
0.633191  7.897869
1.276392  1.920374
0.683442  1.771281
0.864337  3.812513
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df["Data"], df["Current"])
plt.show()
```

(Provided that you have `matplotlib` installed)

Comment: But I am want to update the excel sheet with the plot which we have created .

Comment: https://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.io/ might help then

Comment: I want to read each sheet and then create a plot and update the same sheet which I have .

Comment: As long as you save it, that should achieve it because it directly writes to the xlsx workbook